# Cannot Run pygame on PyCharm

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, pycharm, python-2.6

I'm running python 2.7.10 on Mac OS X El Capitan.
I downloaded pygame 1.9.1 and it works fine on the command line version of Python. However, if i write a program that uses pygame library on PyCharm, it shows a error message like this.

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6 /Users/jeff/PycharmProjects/Codeup/Solution.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jeff/PycharmProjects/Codeup/Solution.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pygame/base.so, 2): Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/A/SDL
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pygame/base.so
  Reason: unsafe use of @executable_path in /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pygame/base.so with restricted binary
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related to El Capitan's new [System Integrity Protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection) (SIP). One of the consequences is that *child* processes have only [restricted access](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/RuntimeProtections/RuntimeProtections.html) to other resources with the goal to make the system less vulnerable. This seems to apply to pycharm that runs python as a child process, whereas you don't have this problem if you run the script from the command-line.

**The dirty solution**: [Disable SIP](http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/05/disable-rootless-system-integrity-protection-mac-os-x/). Try to avoid this.

**The proper solution**: maintain two separate installations of python - the system python (that comes with the OS), and another python that you use for development (dev-python). The latter you can get for example from python.org or through homebrew. Also install setuptools und pip separately and make sure that the python-binaries in `/usr/local/bin` link to the proper counterparts of your dev-python installation. My dev-python installation resides for example under `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/`. Make sure that the different python ecosystems are not mixed up with each other. For example I had once the problem that the build system for some python module was able to discover my dev-python, but later linked to a sys-python lib, which led to problems when I tried to import the python module.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't have SDL library or have some issues with it. 
And also, are you sure you're using Python 2.7.10? In path I see 2.6.